# Mapping NSIndexPaths to data identifiers

Tags: ios, mvvm, swift

I am using a collection view to display data received from a server. The json array of bookings returned is like so:

```
[
    {
        "id": 13644766,
        "check_in": "2014-04-22",
        "check_out": "2014-04-29",
        "property_id": 1980
    },
    {
        "id": 13644763,
        "check_in": "2014-04-22",
        "check_out": "2014-04-29",
        "property_id": 1978
    },
    {
        "id": 13644761,
        "check_in": "2014-04-22",
        "check_out": "2014-04-29",
        "property_id": 2591
    },
    {
        "id": 13644764,
        "check_in": "2014-04-22",
        "check_out": "2014-04-29",
        "property_id": 1978
    }
]
```

I'm using a collection view to display the data and have to implement the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol. More specifically, a section holds all bookings with the same property_id. So i'm having to do a data transformation to map the json array to the sections and items. In Swift after deserializingJSON and data transformation it looks like this (the key is the property_id and value is an array of bookings for that property_id):

```
[
   1980: [["id": 13644766, "check_in": "2014-04-22", "check_out": "2014-04-29"]],
   1978: [
            ["id": 13644763, "check_in": "2014-04-22", "check_out": "2014-04-29"]
            ["id": 13644764, "check_in": "2014-04-22", "check_out": "2014-04-29"]
         ],
   2591: [["id": 13644761, "check_in": "2014-04-22", "check_out": "2014-04-29"]]
]
```

But I would like to keep a simple array in the model layer rather than a dictionary of arrays because it's easier to perform CRUD operations on it than on a dictionary of arrays.

More generally, what I'm asking is this: how can I handle data formatting from the Models to View Controllers (necessary for data source methods `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:`,  `collection:numberOfItemsInSection:` and `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`).

I'm thinking to have a read-only computed property on the bookings array that performs the data transformation. But it might have an impact on performance. If a computed property is not an option how can I keep those two data structures in sync?

Comment: @Rob Napier wrote a few days ago a post about "flattening a mappening". Have a look at it [here](http://robnapier.net/flatmap).

Comment: Would you consider using CoreData to store that info?

Comment: @POB Thanks, I'm reading through.

Comment: @pbasdf No CoreData but a RESTful api to persist bookings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would strongly recommend that you convert your array of dictionaries into an array of objects. JSON should be parsed down to model objects, not down to dictionaries. I've been writing a series on that kind of parsing, starting with [Functional Wish Fulfillment](http://robnapier.net/functional-wish-fulfillment), but you can use any technique you want to do the parsing. Just get it into objects (often structs in Swift). Then you'll have your simple array.

Beyond that, the growing preference to solve "how do I display this" in various Cocoa circles is a transition from the traditional MVC architecture to an MVVM architecture. In an MVVM architecture, you add an extra "View Model" layer between the ViewController and the Model. The job of the ViewModel is to massage the data into a form that the display layers would like it to be in. That may or may not be necessary once you have a good object in your model. But if your Model design doesn't exactly match up to your View needs, a ViewModel is a good intermediary.

Comment: Thanks I will look into the JSON parsing. Yes ideally the model would be of type [Booking] but after data transformation it would be [String : [Booking]] to pass the appropriate section/item information to `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:`, `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` and `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` while the performBatchUpdates methods and RESTful endpoints are typically CRUD operations that would be easier to perform on the _raw_ data. That's perhaps where ReactiveCocoa comes in to keep the model and _transformed_ data in sync?

Comment: ReactiveCocoa is certainly one option here, but you can create VM objects without that. MVVM is a completely separate thing from Reactive programming, though they are popular to use together. I would certainly use a VM object in the case you describe here. Your model->view logic will likely be complex, and it's much easier to put that into its own class. The functional tools discussed in the page I linked and later posts are very well suited to these kinds of data transformations.